# Laravel Relation on Json Array

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent-relationship

i have relation b/w product categories and model where in model i have product_categories_id where i will save `["product_categories_id1","product_categories_id2"]`
so
i have seen this https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations
and used like this in Models.php

```
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;
public function category()
        {
            return $this->belongsToJson(ProductCategory::class, 'product_category_id');
        }
```

but did'nt get the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the field type in model and try it. Also please make sure the array should not have the key.

```
protected $casts = [
       'product_category_id' => 'json',
    ];
```